# Constantly Update Label Widgets From Entry Widgets TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am trying to make a form using TKinter that takes information from a/multiple entry widget(s) and uses them as the value for text widgets.  For example, this could work:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()


e1 = Entry(top)
e2 = Entry(top)
t = Label(top, text = e1.get() + e2.get())
e1.pack()
e2.pack()
t.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

The issue is that this does not automatically update itself.  I know it could be done using a button, but I would like to have the information calculated/updated in the Label widget as the user types into the Entry widgets.  What would be the best was to do this? The following implementation of a while loop does not work as the program enters the top.mainloop() and does not exit:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()


e1 = Entry(top)
e2 = Entry(top)
t = Label(top, text = e1.get() + e2.get())
e1.pack()
e2.pack()

while True:

    t = Label(top, text = e1.get() + e2.get())
    t.pack()
    top.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance.
Six

Comment: With a little more thought, would a top.after-scheduled function work?

Comment: First of all, where are the `StringVar()` and the `textvariable=` argument in Entry widgets? Then you can write inside a function the Label widget, and callback it with the `.after()` method of each Entry widgets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`while True` will not work because `mainloop()` is some kind of `while True` loop and it works all the time till you stop program.

---

You have to use `after(time_in_millisecond, function_name)` which add `function_name` to special queue and `mainloop()` will run it (only once) after `time_in_millisecond`. Executed function can use `after()` to run itself again after `time_in_millisecond`.

---

Second solution: You can use `StringVar` with `Entry` and you can assign function to `StringVar` (using `trace()`) and this function will be executed every time when `StringVar` will be changed.

---

Third solution: you can bind event (`<Key>`) to `Entry` which will call some function when you press key in Entry.

---

Last solution: You can use `validatecommand=` with `validate=` in `Entry` to call some function when text in entry will be changed.

---

See Tkinterbook:
[The Tkinter Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm),
[Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm),
[The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

---

**EDIT:**

Example with `validatecommand=` with `validate=` .

Not all widgets have `validatecommand=`

```
from Tkinter import *

#------------------------------------

def my_validater():
    new_text = e1.get() + e2.get()

    # different method to set label text (without StringVar)
    #t['text'] = new_text
    t.config(text=new_text)

    # validater have to return True or False
    return True 

#------------------------------------

top = Tk()

#---

t = Label(top)
t.pack()

#---

e1 = Entry(top, validate='key', validatecommand=my_validater) # validate every key
e1.pack()

#---

e2 = Entry(top, validate='key', validatecommand=my_validater) # validate every key
e2.pack()

#---

top.mainloop()

#------------------------------------
```

Example with `StringVar` and `trace`

Probably the best solution for most widgets.

```
from Tkinter import *

#------------------------------------

def my_tracer(a, b, c): # trace send 3 arguments to my_tracer
    #print a, b, c

    # using StringVar to get and set text
    new_text = e1_var.get() + e2_var.get()
    t_var.set(new_text)

#------------------------------------

top = Tk()

#---

t_var = StringVar() # or StringVar(top) 

t = Label(top, textvariable=t_var)
t.pack()

#---

e1_var = StringVar() # or StringVar(top) 
e1_var.trace('w', my_tracer) # run my_tracer if value was changed (w = write)

e1 = Entry(top, textvariable=e1_var)
e1.pack()

#---

e2_var = StringVar() # or StringVar(top) 
e2_var.trace('w', my_tracer) # run my_tracer if value was changed (w = write)

e2 = Entry(top, textvariable=e2_var)
e2.pack()

#---

top.mainloop()

#------------------------------------
```

Example with `bind(<Key>, ...)`

Binded function is called before char is placed in `Entry` so you get text without last char in `Entry`. This method is not good for this situation but I keep it.
Eventually you can get `event.char` and add missing char to text.

```
from Tkinter import *

#------------------------------------

def my_bind(event): # bind send 1 argument to my_bind
    # different type of event can have different atributes
    #print event, event.widget, event.char, event.keysym, event.keycode

    new_text = e1.get() + e2.get()
    t.config(text=new_text)

#------------------------------------

top = Tk()

#---

t = Label(top)
t.pack()

#---

e1 = Entry(top)
e1.pack()

e1.bind('<Key>', my_bind)

#---

e2 = Entry(top)
e2.pack()

e2.bind('<Key>', my_bind)

#---

top.mainloop()

#------------------------------------
```

Example with `after()`.

Used for different repeated jobs.

```
from Tkinter import *

#------------------------------------

def my_after(): 
    new_text = e1.get() + e2.get()

    t.config(text=new_text)

    # call again after 100 ms
    top.after(100, my_after)

#------------------------------------

top = Tk()

#---

t = Label(top)
t.pack()

#---

e1 = Entry(top)
e1.pack()

#---

e2 = Entry(top)
e2.pack()

#---

# call first time 
my_after()

# call first time after 100 ms
#top.after(100, my_after)


#---

top.mainloop()

#------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hey, why is the label one character behind?How can i make it real time?

Comment: @0n10n_ it is 3 years old question I don't remeber it

Comment: @0n10n_ `bind('<Key>')` and `bind('<KeyPress>')` execute function before key is send to widget so you can't get last key from widget - `e1.get()`.  `bind('<KeyRelease>')` executes function after key is send to widget so you can get last key from widget - `e1.get()`.